# How I should randomly flip arrow with next arrow?

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating simple game through pygame. In the code arrow is flipping randomly with each pygame. Draw but I want it to flip (randomly when next arrow in the game.

**This is incomplete code**

```
import pygame
import random
import sys
pygame.init()
h=600
w=800
arrow_pos=[w/2,0]
base_size=[w/2,50]
base_pos=[w/4,h-50]
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((w,h))
bg_color=(0,0,0)
base_color=(255,0,0)
arrow_color=(0,150,255)
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
game_over=False
def updating_arrow(arrow_pos):
    if arrow_pos[1]>=0 and arrow_pos[1]<h:
        arrow_pos[1]+=10
    else:
        arrow_pos[1]-=h
    return arrow_pos[1]    
def draw_arrow(screen,arrow_color,arrow_pos,arrow_size):
        pygame.draw.polygon(screen, arrow_color, ((arrow_pos[0], 
        arrow_pos[1]+10), (arrow_pos[0], arrow_pos[1]+20), 
        (arrow_pos[0]+arrow_size, arrow_pos[1]+20), 
        (arrow_pos[0]+arrow_size, 
        arrow_pos[1]+30), (arrow_pos[0]+(arrow_size)*1.5, 
        arrow_pos[1]+15), 
        (arrow_pos[0]+arrow_size, arrow_pos[1]), 
        (arrow_pos[0]+arrow_size, 
        arrow_pos[1]+10)),0)
while not game_over:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
    screen.fill(bg_color)
    arrow_pos[1]=updating_arrow(arrow_pos)

    arrow_size=random.choice([50,-50])
    draw_arrow(screen,arrow_color,arrow_pos,arrow_size)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,base_color, 
    (base_pos[0],base_pos[1],base_size[0],base_size[1]))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Randomly initialize the `arrow_size` before the main loop:

```py
arrow_size = random.choice([50,-50])
while not game_over:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
```

Only change the arrow size, when a new arrow appears at the top of the window. You've to use the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html) to change the value of the globale variable `arrow_size` in the function `updating_arrow`:

```py
def updating_arrow(arrow_pos):
    global arrow_size
    if arrow_pos[1] >= 0 and arrow_pos[1] < h:
        arrow_pos[1] += 10
    else:
        arrow_pos[1] -= h
        arrow_size = random.choice([50,-50])
    return arrow_pos[1]
```

Or pass `arrow_size` to the function by a parameter  and return the changed, as you do it with `arrow_pos`:

```py
def updating_arrow(arrow_pos, arrow_size):
    if arrow_pos[1]>=0 and arrow_pos[1]<h:
        arrow_pos[1]+=10
    else:
        arrow_pos[1]-=h
        arrow_size = random.choice([50,-50])
    return arrow_pos, arrow_size
```

```py
arrow_pos, arrow_size = updating_arrow(arrow_pos, arrow_size) 
# arrow_pos[1]=updating_arrow(arrow_pos) <---- delete
# arrow_size=random.choice([50,-50])     <---- delete
```